# Problema al intercambio de estancias C#

Tags: c#

Ahora tengo mi siguiente duda! en c# tengo una matriz global declarada publica

```
 public string[,] matriz=new string[3,4];
```

ahora, cree un modulo llamado `public void llenar()`para llenar la matriz, pero para acceder al modulo debo crear una nueva instancia de la clase del proyecto.

```
program llen = new program();
    program.llenar();
```

todo bien hasta ahi me llena la matriz y todo, solo que hay un detalle, cree un modulo para mostrar la matriz public void mostrarmatriz(); alli me muestra la matriz, pero antes de llamarlo debo volver a crear otra instancia

```
program ver= new program();
ver.mostrarmatrizr();
```

he aquí que la matriz me aparece vacía. como si nunca la hubiera llenado. porque me ocurre eso

Comment: En c# no existe tal cosa como variable global. Puedes incluir el código completo para entender a que te refieres?

Answer (score 0):

Al ser instancias diferentes sus miembros tienen valores diferentes por eso es que te aparece vacío.

Puedes declarar la variable matriz como estática, te funcionará como la necesitas y no requieres hacer instancias del program, sino solo mandarla llamar como `program.matriz`:

```
public static string[,] matriz=new string[3,4];
```